# Clocking In App for Construction Company Powerapps

Tags: powerapps, mobile-application

I'm building a clocking in app for a construction company, and I'm facing a challenge with a specific feature. The app allows users to log in, select a project, view PDF drawings of buildings, and clock in/out against specific windows or doors within those drawings.

The main issue I'm encountering is finding a suitable solution for the interactive image functionality. I initially used buttons placed over an image, but this approach becomes cumbersome for the company's administrators since buildings can have hundreds of windows, and we have numerous projects. Creating each page manually would be impractical. I also tried using HTML mapping, but it didn't work as expected. Additionally, using an SVG by manually editing the code for each path would be too technically complex for the admin team.

I'm seeking guidance on whether there is a dynamic way to implement this feature or if it exceeds the capabilities of PowerApps. Alternatively, if there are existing apps available that already provide this functionality, I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

It's crucial that the app works offline, so developing a bespoke website accessible on mobile devices would not be a feasible solution.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: when someone clicks the part of the image it takes in the window/ door id and transfers them to another page which gives them the option to clock in against that element.